# How to sort django queryset with two fields as a combined field

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a `Deadline` model which have two fields, `start_date` and `end_date`.
I want to sort the queryset with both the fields but have a copy of deadline for each date

I tried creating annotated common fields and ordering through that.

```
class Deadline(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField

dl_start = deadline_queryset.annotate(date=F('start_date'))
dl_end = deadlien_queryset.annotate(date=F('end_date'))
dl_all = dl_start.union(dl_end).order_by('date')
```

I need a timeline of events. 
Consider if my queryset  has 2 objects:

```
Deadline <id: 1, start_date: 12-dec, end_date: 24-jan>
Deadline <id: 2, start_date: 15-dec, end_date: 21-jan>
```

I need a list of deadlines like:

```
Deadline <id: 1, start_date: 12-dec, end_date: 24-jan, date: 12-dec>
Deadline <id: 2, start_date: 15-dec, end_date: 21-jan, date: 15-dec>
Deadline <id: 2, start_date: 15-dec, end_date: 21-jan, date: 21-jan>
Deadline <id: 1, start_date: 12-dec, end_date: 24-jan, date: 24-jan>
```

Comment: Do you want to print like 12 dec, 24 jan and then 15 dec, 21 jan?

Comment: @ShafikurRahmanShaon I want something like 12-dec, 15-dec, 21-jan, 24-jan along with the whole object

Comment: What do you means by 2 deadline object? Do sorting(by start_date, end_date) over the `Deadline` objects help you?

Comment: If you want to filter certain dates then put those date in a list and use the `__in` operator to filter for them. more on `__in` here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my aforementioned code, the annotated fields were not being carry forward after the union and so I was unable to use order_by on it.

It worked after using the following variation:

```
dl_start = deadline_queryset.annotate(date=F('start_date')).values('id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'date')
dl_end = deadlien_queryset.annotate(date=F('end_date')).values('id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'date')
dl_all = dl_start.union(dl_end).order_by('date')
```

This helped me carry forward the annotated `date` field.